# How to derive the response function of $m\ddot x + \gamma \dot x + kx = f$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, oscillators, dissipation, fluctuation-dissipation

In a lecture on fluctuation-dissipation theorem, it is stated that

> EOM: $m\ddot x + \gamma \dot x + kx = f$
>
> Response function $\chi(\omega) = (-m \omega^2 + i\gamma \omega +
> > k)^{-1}$

However, I can't understand how they derived the response function directly from EOM for a deterministic system; the instructor framed it as if it is trivial but I'm lost at this point.

Comment: Supposing your have a funciton solution written in its complex genral form of $x(t)=Ae^{-i\omega t}$ for homogeneous solution (otherwise $f$ must be precised) the derivitatio gives your response function. We suppose here the system to response at a unique frequency which is convenient with the fact your Diff EQ is linear hence the system modelized as linear (which explain to get a $x(t)$ at a unique given  frequency$